# Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose Ms. Lee is buying a new house and must borrow 150,000. She wants a 
30-year mortgage and she has two choices. She can either borrow money at 7% per 
year with no points, or she can borrow the money at 6.5% per year with a charge of 
3 points. (A "point" is a fee of 1% of the loan amount that the borrower pays the 
lender at the beginning of the loan. For example, a mortgage with 3 points requires 
Ms. Lee to pay 4,500 extra to get the loan.) As an approximation, we assume that 
interest is compounded and payments are made continuously. Let

$$M(t) = \text{amount owed at time } t\ \left(\text{measured in years}\right)$$
$$r= \text{annual interest rate, and}$$
$$p= \text{annual payment}$$

Then the model for the amount owed is

$$ \frac{dM}{dt}=rM-p$$

Q.How much does Ms Lee has to pay in each case?

I have tried solving the DE, and i get
$$ M(t)=C_1e^{rt} + \frac{p}{r}$$

Now what to do?

Comment: What is the s in $\frac{s}{r}$? Now you know what M($0$) should be, right? It is the amount owed at the beginning, which should give you a value for $C_1$, so that you have a formula for $M(t)$. If I understood the problem well, the payments will be made over 30 years. If this is the case, the formula M(t) for t=30 and r=$7%$% and for M(t) for t=30 and $6.5%$%+ $4,500 should give you different values, which you can compare to each other.

Comment: thanks, Gary. $\frac{s}{r}$ should actually be $$\frac{p}{r}$$. As for $M(0)$ is the amount she owed at the beginning of the time, it's an unknown. we only know $M(30)$ which is equal to $0$.

Comment: Why do you assume continuous compounding and payments? I've always seen this kind of problem handled by difference equations (recurrence relations), rather than differential equations.

Comment: @Gerry:  Maybe you don't want to use continuous compounding, but the bank does.  Or maybe a writer wants to use it in his differential equations textbook.

Comment: With the exception of consumer and small business loans, continuous compounding is standard.

Comment: @user6312, really? I thought continuous compounding didn't exist outside of math texts. The interest is increasing while you're standing in line at the bank to pay it!

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: Yes, that's why they have so few tellers. More seriously, it really is the norm, for example, in interbank transactions. But being practically minded, they round billion dollar transactions to the nearest cent.

Answer (score 1):

We can work with concrete numbers, or develop a general formula.  Ideally, you should do both, as an exercise and a partial check.  Let's develop a general formula. I will use your notation, but introduce two new symbols. Let $N$ be the amortization period, that is, the number of years until the mortgage is paid off. In our case, $N=30$.  Let $A$ be the initial amount owed.  With no "points", $A=150000$.  With $3$ points, she needs to borrow $150000/(1.03)$ in order to have $150000$ left after paying the points. The general equation for the amount owed is, as you wrote,
$$M(t)=C_1e^{rt}+\frac{p}{r}$$
This is the *general* solution of the equation, but it is incomplete until we evaluate the constant $C_1$. (Technical note: It will turn out, of course, that $C_1$ is negative, else what we owe would increase rapidly forever. I would have preferred to arrange things so that any constant is positive.)

Note that $M(0)=A$ and $M(N)=0$. We obtain the two equations 
$$A=C_1+\frac{p}{r}$$
$$0=C_1e^{rN} +\frac{p}{r}$$
Subtract, to get rid of the $p/r$ term. We get
$$A=C_1(1-e^{rN})$$
So $C_1=-\frac{A}{e^{rN}-1}$ and we obtain the equation
$$M(t)=\frac{p}{r} -\frac{A}{e^{rN}-1}e^{rt}$$

Now that we have full information about $M(t)$, we should be able to answer any question.  In particular, by taking $t=N$, we have
$$0=\frac{p}{r} -\frac{A}{e^{rN}-1}e^{rN}$$
Now we can solve for the payment $p$:
$$p=rA\frac{e^{rN}}{e^{rN}-1}=\frac{rA}{1-e^{-rN}}$$
and easily find $p$ given any  $r$, $N$, and $A$.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate how much she borrows with $3$ points, she gets $0.97$ of the amount borrowed, so $M(0)=150,000/0.97$, which is slightly higher than $154,500$.  Now if you incorporate $M(0)$ and $M(30)$ you can solve for $C_1$ and $p$ and pick the choice with lower $p$