# Are this equations somehow equivalent? (newbie mistakes...)

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, finance

When reading the next question about Differential Equations and their application in Finance (in this scenario they are modelling Annuities; [Differential Equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48871/differential-equation))
The Differential equation is:

$$\frac{dM}{dt} = rM - p$$

And the solution may have been derived as

$$dM = r(M-\frac{p}{r})dt$$

$$\frac{dM}{M - \frac{p}{r}} = r dt$$

After the integrals:

$$ln(M - \frac{p}{r}) = rt + c$$

$$M = e^{rt+c} + \frac{p}{r}$$

$$M = Ce^{rt} + \frac{p}{r}$$

I tried to solve that equation before watching their solution, but forgot to divide everything by r.
So I did:

$$dM = (rM-p)dt$$

$$\frac{dM}{rM-p} = dt$$

After the integration

$$ln(rM - p) = t + c$$

$$M = \frac{e^{t+c} + p}{r}$$

$$M = \frac{Ce^{t} + p}{r}$$

I think that this equations are certainly not the same.

$$Ce^{rt} + \frac{p}{r} \neq \frac{Ce^{t} + p}{r}$$

Can you explain me what's wrong in the second process? (Or if they are the same, how is the $r$ embedded in the constant $C$?)

Comment: When you do integration, it is not $\ln(rM-p)$. If you differentiate that again, by the chain rule, $r$ pops out and it becomes $\frac{rdM}{rM-p}$.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because @Riemann's comment answers it.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it was really useful. How do I close a question? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second approach, in fact $\int \frac{1}{rM-p}dM = \frac{1}{r}\ln(rM-p)$. So $\frac{1}{r}\ln(rM-p) = t + c \implies M = \frac{e^{rt + rc} + p}{r} = Ce^{rt} + \frac{p}{r}$, where I defined $C =  \frac{e^{rc}}{r}$. Since r and c are constants this is possible.